# Prevent arrow key from scrolling with keydown event

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a game captured inside of an Iframe within my body. Problem is, the entire page scrolls when the arrow keys are pressed. How can I prevent this? I don't want to disable scrolling with the arrow keys alogether, only when the game is being played.

Comment: I updated the demo to make the functionality more clear :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable as a flag and add an event listener to see if that flag is present, if so, disable the key: **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/uDoJIMe/4/edit)**

```
var flag = true;

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var badKey = 40; //down array keyCode
  if (flag && e.keyCode === badKey) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a key listener and stop the normal functioning of specific inputs based on conditions (like while playing a game)